# sql optimize search many-many

Tags: sql, mysql, database, hibernate

```
usertable
----
id, username

grouptable
----
id, groupname

group_user
--------
uid, gid

books
----
id, groupname
```

Input parameters:  groupname, username
output:  list of books

Is it possible to use 1 sql statement to get list of books when username is inside groupname

Question 2:  any good book to recommand to master complex sql statement..

Comment: You should not put two questions in one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gives list of books by user parametar

```
SELECT b.id,
FROM usertable u
     INNER JOIN group_user gu ON gu.uid = u.id
     INNER JOIN grouptable g ON g.id= gu.gid
     INNER JOIN books b ON b.groupname = g.groupname 
WHERE u.username = @user_name
```

Also i think if you have the group name you can use

```
SELECT b.id,
FROM grouptable g 
     INNER JOIN books b ON b.groupname = g.groupname 
WHERE g.groupname = @group_name
```

Bus having select on both parameters i think is not very good think. This query will get
list of books for user group name

```
SELECT b.id,
    FROM usertable u
         INNER JOIN group_user gu ON gu.uid = u.id
         INNER JOIN grouptable g ON g.id= gu.gid
              AND g.group_name = @group_name
         INNER JOIN books b ON b.groupname = g.groupname 
    WHERE u.username = @user_name
```

Comment: just to confirm,  u are using inner join. but  same user can have multiple different books.   inner join means  1 left table-1 right table join(full join) in this case unique user will be listed which is incorrect..?  sorry if i'm wrong and please explain

Comment: using the Where clause i leave only one row in the usertable the user with username the same as the parameter value. Using inner join i get as many rows as user is part of. So if user is in 5 groups i get five row. Then i filter these groups by parameter @group_name. The i get book list for this group. If it is still not clear how it works just replace "b.id" with "*" and remove all the inner join and the where clause and start adding them one by one to see the effect